# Arithmetic mean - who, when?

Tags: mathematics

We are sitting in class and I was wondering: who came up with the arithmetic mean?

Who proposed it or who mentioned it first in his/her work? Google showed the oldest mentions in 1750-1800 but...

We looked at Wikipedia but didn't find the answer.

Thank you for any lead, as even the teacher doesn't know.

Comment: Arithmetic mean is used from the times immemorial. We do not have sources from that times, thus the question has no definite answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source is ancient Greek mathematics: at least the Pythagorean [Archytas](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/archytas/#Math).

The early extant souce seems to be [Fragment 2](https://books.google.it/books?id=2ietQ7tX8TEC&pg=PA163) of the lost work of *On Music* [cited by Porphyry, *On Ptolemy’s Harmonics*, 1.5] :

> And Archytas speaking about the means writes these things:
>
> > “There are three means in music: one is the arithmetic [*αριθμητικά*], the second geometric [*γεωμετρικά*] and the third sub-contrary [, which they call “harmonic”].